# How to get monthly time series cross sectional into zoo using R

Tags: r

I want to get a panel data set into zoo so that it catches both month and year. My data set looks like this. 
[image: dat]

and the data can be downloaded from [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13JGhFSF9st462bKDEIlUiSd-uaYfU3bzF02df-zM214/edit#gid=1243672642&vpid=A1).

The best way I could do is,

```
dat<-read.csv("dat_lag.csv")
zdat <- read.zoo(dat, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

However, I could do this by including column 1- *Date* and column 4- *Day* in my data set. Is there any clever way to get both month and year into zoo using R without including the *Date* and *Day* columns? Thanks, in advance for any help.

Comment: Why do you need either year or day? That information is in the Date column which became the index for zdat.

Comment: Doo, do read in columns and leave out others you can use the `colClasses` parameter with `read.csv`. Assuming the file is in your working directory: 
`read.csv('dat_lag.csv',colClasses = c('NULL','numeric','character','NULL','factor','factor','numeric’))` will leave out the “Date" and “Day” columns.

Comment: @42, my data set is required only year and month because the resolution of data is monthly. "Date" column indicate the first day of month, which is not correct.

Comment: @hvollmeier, I want to get the year and month to indexed in zoo, perhaps if we remove the unnecessary columns such as Date and Day using your answer